# How to sum up row values in dataframe based on groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a use case where I am getting larger csv file,  need to perform groupby on three-column labels and need to sum up matching row values for the particular column if it is an integer if it's a string that should replace with “NA”
I tried doing using pandas stuck up to proceed, not sure does this required any in memory operation.

```
Import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(“input.csv")
data = df.groupby([‘X’,’Y’,’Z’])[‘ADJ’].sum()
print(data)
```

The input.csv..
[image]

The output.csv(dataframe)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code did not work, but what you can do is `groupby.sum` with numeric_only and then `reindex` with all the columns not in the ones used for grouping then `reset_index` like:

```
# dummy example
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':list('aaaabbbb'), 'Y':list('cccdeeee'), 'Z':list('ffgghhii'), 
                   'ADJ':range(8), 'BJC': ['z']*8, 
                   'JBC': range(10,18), 'MNK':['y']*8})

# create data
data = df.groupby(['X', 'Y', 'Z']).sum(numeric_only=True)\
         .reindex(columns=set(df.columns)-set(['X', 'Y', 'Z']))\
         .reset_index()
print (data)
   X  Y  Z  MNK  BJC  JBC  ADJ
0  a  c  f  NaN  NaN   21    1
1  a  c  g  NaN  NaN   12    2
2  a  d  g  NaN  NaN   13    3
3  b  e  h  NaN  NaN   29    9
4  b  e  i  NaN  NaN   33   13
```

Comment: T, that's what I am looking for it. Thank you.

Comment: what would be change if there is column(s) which has mixed data type values say numeric or string. the strig values will be ignored and numeric values should get added

Comment: @user2927486 have a look at [pd.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with the parameters `errors='ignore'`. Use it on your column(s) before, to change the string to `nan` that will be then ignored during the `groupby.sum`